# What is meant by this use of quotation marks?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

I was reading an article [Meet the Artist Who Blows Things Up for a Living](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/Meet-the-Artist-Who-Blows-Things-Up-for-a-Living-199046161.html?c=y&story=fullstory)

in 4th paragraph the author says

> When I visit Cai (as everyone calls him, pronouncing it “Tsai”) in his spare East 
>       Village Manhattan studio with a big red door and a feng shui stone lion guarding the 
>       entrance within, we sit at a glass table flanked by wall-size wood screens: his gunpowder “drawings.”

I didn't understand why author puts *drawings* in double quotes. If you read the article, he has used it for many other words like  *“signs”*, *“crop circle”*. 
My question is what the intends by putting the words in double quotes?

Comment: They are known as 'scare quotes,' quotation marks placed around a word or phrase to imply that it may not signify its apparent meaning or that it is not necessarily the way the quoting person would express its concept. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes

Comment: For the colon use, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29

Comment: I removed the second question about colon use because it is completely unrelated to the first question. Since this is a Q&A site, it is expected that each post contains just one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotation marks are [signalling unusual usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Signaling_unusual_usage):

> Quotation marks are often used to alert readers that a term is used in a nonstandard, ironic, or other special sense.* [[CMoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style)]

A drawing is normally made with crayon, chalk or pen on papaer. Not with gunpowder on a wood screen.  Hence the "what I (or the artist) will now call a drawing".

The colon is used to let the viewer know that his wall sized screens are the drawings mentioned

A crop circle is flattened corn on a field, but one of the "drawings" resemble a crop circle so it is in quotation marks